# different directive in angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular 2.

Can someone please explain the difference between the html directives and attribute directives? Why are they both needed?

Example:

`<rating [rate]="rate" (rate-change)="onUpdate($event)"></rating>`

So:

`rating` is what i call "html directive" but I'm not sure what it's for?

`[rate]` is an attribute directive that sets component property named "rate".

`(rate-change)` is an attribute directive that calls a component method called rateChange.

Any other types of directives?

Answer (score 2):

So let's take this in parts:

- `rating` is a [component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html). A component in angular 2, is single piece of running code, composed by a typescript file (using @Component decorator), plus a template and some styling. If you come from angular 1 world, it is kind of similar to a element directive
- `[rate]` is an [attribute directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html). Basically they bind a value (rate in this case) to any html attribute.
- `(rate-change)` is an [event handler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding). In this case, it is custom event that you can trigger using [EventEmmiter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

Comment: what is the difference between `input property from a Component` to `members of a component` ?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, could you elaborate on that @EladBenda?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got confused with the naming. Let's try to get things in order:

In you example,
`rating` is a [component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#components). This is Angular's way to create new DOM elements with custom behavior. Its code is most likely to look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rating'
  ...
})
```

`[rate]` is the tricky one, because from this narrow context it can be either an [input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs) property of the `rating` component, or an unrelated [attribute directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html).

`(rate-change)` is an event handler, in this case it's an [output](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs) of the `rating` component because it's not a standard DOM event (like `click`).

Comment: `rating is a component.` but it's not really needed. right? we could have add a css id #my-id and call selector: `#my-id`. true?

Comment: what is the difference between `input property from a Component` to `members of a component` ?